# BlackBerry - Multiple Screens or Single Screen with Content Manager?

Tags: design-patterns, blackberry, screen

I've seen projects which use many screens each one for different layout and functionality.

I've seen projects with only one screen (like wizard workflow) where content is changed on user interaction (and this seems to be logical to use single screen in wizards).

But also I've seen projects (apps like game or messenger or phone settings utility) which use single screen for different functionalities.

I can see such advantages of having single screen in app:

- keep same decoration design and menu or toolbar (which may be also achieved with inheritance)
- keep single screen in ui stack (which may be achieved by pop/push screen)
- easy to handle data over application

Can you tell other advantages/disadvantages of single screen app?
When its better to use this approach?

Thank you!

[This question on BlackBerry Support Community Forums](http://rim.lithium.com/t5/Java-Development/BlackBerry-Multiple-Screens-or-Single-Screen-with-Content/td-p/485643)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For us it depends on the screen. We have some screens that achieve common goals such as a popup with a list control or a progress bar. Most of our screens are separated by functionality. I think that helps to prevent things from being convoluted.

We do reuse the callbacks for list controls and tree fields etc where the functionality of the particular control is almost always the same.

I have had some of the same confusion, many people suggest using single classes to limit the footprint on the device, but others say with newer devices it doesn't much matter.